# Build a 3D Book Preview with user uploaded images

Tags: library, 3d, modeling

My plan is to build a website very similar to https://buch-konfigurator.brandbook.de/. So I'll have a book which I can edit in some aspects.

The biggest hurdle is to get a user uploaded image on that book and generate a 3D preview out of it. Can you recommend me any software/library which can handle this on a website?